# The reference operator [] on STL set

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, reference, set

I am just getting familiar with the STL and I can't quite understand why the `operator []` gives an error.

```
        int main(){
          set< int > s;
          for(int i=0; i<=1000; i++) s.insert((i*1777)%123);
          for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++) cout<<s[i]<<endl;
        }
```

Then I tried this and got another error message

```
        int main(){
          set< int > s;
          for(int i=0; i<=1000; i++) s.insert((i*1777)%123);
          for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++) cout<<*(s.begin() + i)<<endl;
        }
```

**I understand why it doesn't have members like `push_back`, `pop_back` and all but I don't understand why these two methods of referencing don't work (but they do for `vector` and `string`). I understand that these operators weren't overloaded in the library, but why?**

After some web searches I did figure out how to reference it

```
        int main(){
          set< int > s;
          for(int i=0; i<=1000; i++) s.insert((i*1777)%123);
          for(set< int >::iterator i=s.begin(); i!=s.end(); i++) cout<<*i<<endl;
        }
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the STL `set` doesn't have `operator[]`.  Are you sure that first code example compiles?

Comment: @templatetypedef it didn't compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard does not specify those operators for a set or its iterators, because those are not efficient ways to access a set.  A set has bidirectional iterators.  This means that in order to move to the nth element in the iteration sequence, you need to iterate over every element in between.  So, for example, if operator+ were to be implemented for a set's iterators, internally, it would be something like this:

```
iterator operator+(iterator it, size_t n)
{
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        ++it;
    return it;
}
```

So, in other words, it would be an O(n) operation.  If you were to iterate over the set like you are doing in your for loop, it becomes an O(n^2) for loop.  The same thing applies if `operator[]` was implemented.  Because of this, no one with efficiency in mind would want to use these operators, and so they are not implemented.

Comment: Thank you. this make better sense than what I've gotten. Most people are just telling me what I already knew.

Comment: Sets don't have an "nth element". They are unordered.

Comment: @Daniel: Are you familiar with C++?  That's the language we're talking about here.  In particular, `std::set`, from its standard library, which is most certainly ordered.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, yes I am familiar with C++. Your explanation doesn't give a good reason why there isn't a `[]` operator for sets. Sure you can use iterators to access them "sequentially" but that's just because you have to access them in some order. `set` is trying to mimic mathematical sets which is unordered. If the STL writers had wanted to, they could have implemented `operator[]` using iterators.

Comment: @Daniel: Performance is good enough reason, similarly std::list doesn't have random access iterators, for the same reason even if order makes perfect sense for list. std::set with default comparator containing 1,2,3 will have 2n'd element 2. And when you iterate set you can expect that each next element will be bigger than previous one.

Comment: @Daniel: They could have, yes.  But they didn't.  And the reason they didn't is outlined in my answer. And `std::set` is a rough equivalent to a mathematical set, true.  But in fact, it is specified as more than that.  In particular, it is specified as ordered.  The Standard Library authors didn't *have* to specify it as ordered, but in fact they did.  It could be implemented as a hash set, like `std::unordered_set` is, and it would meet your requirement of being able to be accessed in "some order".  But it's not.

Comment: The key thing that people miss here (and I have to continually remind myself) is that Stepanov and Lee implemented lean-and-mean generic components, not high-level concepts.  The naming of some of these components (e.g. `std::set`) is unfortunate, as they don't even remotely resemble the high-level concepts people expect them to be.

Answer (score 2):

well, it is because `std::set` doesn't provide subscript `operator[]` what is completely understandable because of nature of set. What it should mean set[4]? Mathematically this is not correct. In mathematics set1={1,2,3,4} and set2={4,3,2,1} are equal, so how it still would be true if every two set1[n] and set2[n] of these sets are different (in case of `std::set` the elements are sorted however, so it would be the same)? So `std::set` doesn't have subscript `operator[]` however you can still iterate through this container.

```
int myints1[]= {10,20,30,40,50};
int myints2[]= {50,40,30,20,10}; 
std::set<int> s1 (myints1,myints1+5);
std::set<int> s2(myints2,myints2+5); // Internally, the elements in a set are 
                                     // always sorted following a specific strict
                                     // weak ordering criterion indicated by its
                                     // internal comparison object, so this set
                                     // will be the same as s2
if(s1==s2){
    printf("sets: true");
}else printf("sets: false");
std::set<int>::iterator it2=s2.begin();
for(std::set<int>::iterator it1=s1.begin();it1!=s1.end();it1++){
            printf("\ns1: %d  s2: %d",*it1,*it2);
    it2++;
}
```

> output:
>
> sets: true
>
> s1: 10  s2: 10
>
> s1: 20  s2: 20
>
> s1: 30  s2: 30
>
> s1: 40  s2: 40
>
> s1: 50  s2: 50

Answer (score 1):

STL set does not overload the subscript operator `[]`. You cannot access STL set elements using subscript operator directly like with other containers such as `vector`. 
You can find a complete reference of STL set here:[STL set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer my question. I am trying to understand why these operators were not overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

@BenjaminLindley is right in pointing out that `T& operator[](std::size_t)` does not make sense for containers without random access iterators, because all random access loops would be of `O(N^2)` complexity (linear in the outer loop over elements, times linear in the `std::advance` on the iterators). For that reason out of the **Sequence Containers**, only `std::array`, `std::vector` and `std::deque` provide `operator[]`, but `std::list` (bidirectional iterators) and `std::forward_list` (forward iterators) do not.

The **Ordered Associative Containers** (`std::set`, `std::map`, and their multi cousins) only provide bidirectional iterators, and the **Unordered Associative Containers** (`std::unordered_set`, `std::unorderd_map` and their multi cousins) have at least forward iterators. They also don't have `operator[](std::size_t)` as a member. You therefore need to write `std::advance(my_set.begin(), n)` instead of `my_set[n]`, which makes the `O(N)` complexity of such a call painfully obivous.

Just as an added note: the map-like containers contain Key-Value pairs and the associative nature of these containers is expressed through another `operator[]`, but not indexed by an offset, but rather with an "associated" Key and they have signature `Value& operator[](Key const&)` (and an rvalue-reference overload since C++11). These operators have `O(log N)` complexity for `std::map` and amortized `O(1)` complexity for `std::unordered_map`. This will give e.g. loops over all keys of these containers `O(N log N)` and `O(N)` complexity, respectively.

The associative `operator[]` versions also have **insert semantics**: calls like `my_map[my_key] = my_value;` will attempt to insert the pair `my_key, my_value` into the map, and return an iterator if such an element already exists. Note that that are also no `const` overloads for theses associative element accesses: use the `find()` member functions for that.

For `std::set` an overloaded `operator[](Key const&)` does not make any sense, since it would only express the fact that the key is associated to itself, and the insert semantics is already more directly expressed through the `insert()` member function.

Answer (score 1):

If each node of a BST maintained a count of its descendants, the BST's i-th element could be found in O(log(n)) time and size of the overall tree could be returned in O(1) time.  The overhead would be O(log(n)) on each insertion and deletion, which are already O(log(n))-time operations.